# Printing sub strings from command line arguments, in C

Tags: c, command-line, string, arguments

Why doesn't this work.

```
printf("%s\n", argv[1][3]);
```

When this works?

```
printf("%c\n", argv[1][3]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the `%s` format specifier tells `printf` that the argument is a null-terminated string.  You're giving `printf` a single character--the fourth character in the second element of the `argv` array.

If you want to print the substring from the fourth character to the end of the string, you can do that too, you just have to get a pointer to that character:

```
printf("%s\n", &argv[1][3]);
```

or, if you prefer:

```
printf("%s\n", argv[1] + 3);
```

Comment: But it is a null terminated string, I just want it to start from offset 3 and keep printing until null.

How would I achieve the same thing then?

Comment: Thank you, I just saw that you added some info to your comment.

Answer (score 2):

"%s" in a foramt string expects a 'char *' argument, but you're passing it a 'char' so you get garbage (probably a crash).  "%c" in a format string expects a 'char' argument, which is what you are giving it, so it works.

Comment: Less likely a crash than a compiler error. GCC (at least) can do type checking for format-string functions like `printf` and `scanf`.